# iOS : CGRect of a Specific Text in a String of a UILabel

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, core-text

I want to know what frame will a string be at after it is drawn in rect.

```
NSString *string = @"This is a sample text.";
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = string;
// do some setups here
```

In `drawInRect:` method, I want to retrieve the frame of the a specific word. Let's say I want to know the rect for `sample` from `This is a sample text.` string.

Here's a sample `UILabel` and I want to know the frame of the text inside the red box. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: hmm.. interesting..Can u give any insights on what you are trying to accomplish with this..?? SO that one can know if there is another way to do it..?? Does this help you..? https://gist.github.com/erkie/1278483

Comment: For example, I want to draw a box or a background image on the frame.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by deciding perticular pixel for one character

i.e. suppose character 'R' takes 8 pixel in X co- ordinate. like this by multiplying `8* number of characters in the label` you can get frame

Answer (score 0):

```
1]Create a CGRect.

 CountRect=CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,
                         rect.origin.y+22 + (rect.size.height - height)/2,
                         rect.size.width,
                         (rect.size.height - height)/2);

2]set NSString which contain string.(your case only contain sample)

  NSString* myNewString;

3]set NSString to CGRect.

  [myNewString drawInRect:CountRect 
withFont:fontlineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
  [myNewString drawInRect:CountRect withAttributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score -1):

you not get frame for particular word in UILabel,you only get UILabel frame,you divide string into words,like this

```
NSArray *stringArray = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

add UILabel and text & frame for each UILabel

```
int x=0;
int y=0;

for(int i=0;i<stringArray.count;i++)
    {
        CGSize size =[[stringArray objectAtIndex:i] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChaparralPro-Bold" size:fontSize ]];
        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
         if(x+size.width >320)
           {
             y=y+size.height;
             x=0;
           }
        label.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,size.width,size.height);
        x=x+size.width;
        label.text=[wordsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        label.textColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x3a5670);
        label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChaparralPro-Bold" size:fontSize];
        label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [label release];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the size of string by using function:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font; 
CGSize wordSize = [@"sample" sizeWithFont:font];
```

You can iterate through all the words and newline and get the frames of each words accordingly